# Installing Oracle Client 12c release 2 Error

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracleclient

I download the oracle 12c client 64 bit version from the oracle official site and tried to install. As soon as i run the setup file it gives the following error and stop running the setup. could someone suggest the reason for this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please copy the text of the errors from the install window, edit your question, and replace the image with the actual text. Thanks.

Comment: Actually the window closes as soon as errors occur. it gives milliseconds to take the print screen too. thanks

Comment: Are you logged in as user with Admin privileges?

Answer (score 0):

The installer copies a set of files required to initiate the installation process to a temporary area.  The avoids a chicken-and-egg problem when it comes to doing de-installations, ie, running a de-installer from the media you are wanting to deinstall.

The error above suggests that you could not write to your standard TEMP area, or it was full.  So you could try something like:

1. create a folder c:\tmp  (assuming c:\ has plenty of space)
2. set TEMP and TMP to c:\tmp using PC => Manage => Advanced =>
   ENvironment Var
3. run setup.exe as before

You should then see something like:

"Preparing to run installer from c:\tmp\OraInstall..."

Comment: I did exactly as you said. but i'm still having the same problem.